# Configuring IP Tables

Tags: iptables, centos6.5

I want to make sure that the only network traffic on my linux CentOS server is my own.

All my server runs is a Tomcat instance with one servlet.  This servlet takes a parameter, which is a URL to download.  It will download from that url, and pass the contents back to the calling program through the usual http response.

I want to block all network traffic to this server except

1) Ability to ssh

2) Ability to download from host abc.xyz.com

3) Ability for server with IP 111.222.333.444 to download from me

Can someone please tell me the commands to do this in iptables?  I tried finding this out myself but I was a bit out my depth with the lingo.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Configuring a firewall is simple, first of all select what ports you want to be open.

For example Webserver ports:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

For example SSH port:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

In any way your server is able to download files from other server/hosts.

> 3) Ability for server with IP 111.222.333.444 to download from me

I suppose that must be port 80, (or any port where the server is downloading from) if your uploading files to your website.

After these steps you need to look if the firewall is configured right:

```
iptables -L -n
```

If it's looking good then you're able to save your iptables, and restart the service.

*If there is any problem configureren your firewall, please let me know.*